# Throwing Exceptions in an SPL autoloader?

Tags: php, spl

Is there a way to throw exceptions from an SPL Autoloader in PHP in case it fails? It doesn't seem to work under PHP 5.2.11.

```
class SPLAutoLoader{

    public static function autoloadDomain($className) {
        if(file_exists('test/'.$className.'.class.php')){
            require_once('test/'.$className.'.class.php');
            return true;
        }       

        throw new Exception('File not found');
    }

} //end class

//start
spl_autoload_register( array('SPLAutoLoader', 'autoloadDomain') );

try{
    $domain = new foobarDomain();
}catch(Exception $c){
    echo 'File not found';
}
```

When the above code is called, there is no sign of an exception, instead I get a standard "Fatal error: Class 'foobarDomain' not found in bla". And the execution of the script terminates.

Comment: What happens, exactly?  You've only said it fails, but not how it fails.

Comment: When the above code is called, there is no sign of an exception, instead I get a standard "Fatal error: Class 'foobarDomain' not found in bla". And the execution of the script terminates.

Comment: Great, thanks.  What happens when you throw the exception first thing in the function, prior to the inclusion?

Comment: It seems as though I have discovered Yet Another PHP Bug

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's [a design decision](http://www.php.net/autoload):

> **Note**: Exceptions thrown in `__autoload` function cannot be caught in the `catch` block and results in a fatal error.

The reason is that there may be more than one autoload handlers, in which case, you don't want the first handler to throw an Exception and bypass the second handler. You want your second handler to have a chance at autoloading its classes. If you use a library which makes use of the autoloading feature, you don't want it bypassing your autoload handler because they throw Exceptions inside their autoloader.

If you want to check whether or not you can instantiate a class, then use [`class_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) and pass `true` as the second argument (or leave it out, `true` is the default):

```
if (class_exists('foobarDomain', $autoload = true)) {
    $domain = new foobarDomain();
} else {
    echo 'Class not found';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- you saved the day!

Comment: This behaviour changed in PHP 5.3 - exceptions can now be thrown and caught in the autoloader. However, you need to be careful if you have multiple autoloaders registered.

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments in [the documentation for spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), it's possible to call another function from the autoloader, which in turn would throw the exception.

```
class SPLAutoLoader{

    public static function autoloadDomain($className) {
        if(file_exists('test/'.$className.'.class.php')){
            require_once('test/'.$className.'.class.php');
            return true;
        }       
        self::throwFileNotFoundException();
    }

    public static function throwFileNotFoundException()
    {
        throw new Exception('File not found');
    }

} //end class

//start
spl_autoload_register( array('SPLAutoLoader', 'autoloadDomain') );

try{
    $domain = new foobarDomain();
}catch(Exception $c){
    echo 'File not found';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Same error and no exception thrown :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full-fledged factory object which demonstrates auto-loading, namespaces support, callables from non-static instances (with variable paths), handling of loading errors and custom exceptions.

```
abstract class AbstractFactory implements \ArrayAccess
{
    protected $manifest;
    function __construct($manifest)
    {
        $this->manifest = $manifest;
    }

    abstract function produce($name);

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->manifest[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return $this->produce($offset);
    }
    //implement stubs for other ArrayAccess funcs
}


abstract class SimpleFactory extends AbstractFactory {

    protected $description;
    protected $path;
    protected $namespace;

    function __construct($manifest, $path, $namespace = "jj\\") {
        parent::__construct($manifest);
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->namespace = $namespace;
        if (! spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoload'), false)) //throws exceptions on its own, but we want a custom one
            throw new \RuntimeException(get_class($this)." failed to register autoload.");
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        spl_autoload_unregister(array($this, 'autoload'));
    }

    public function autoload($class_name) {
        $file = str_replace($this->namespace, '', $class_name);
        $filename = $this->path.$file.'.php';
        if (file_exists($filename))
            try {
                require $filename; //TODO add global set_error_handler and try clause to catch parse errors
            } catch (Exception $e) {} //autoload exceptions are not passed by design, nothing to do
    }

    function produce($name) {
        if (isset($this->manifest[$name])) {
            $class = $this->namespace.$this->manifest[$name];
            if (class_exists($class, $autoload = true)) {
                return new $class();
            } else throw new \jj\SystemConfigurationException('Factory '.get_class($this)." was unable to produce a new class {$class}", 'SYSTEM_ERROR', $this);
//an example of a custom exception with a string code and data container

        } else throw new LogicException("Unknown {$this->description} {$name}.");
    }

    function __toString() //description function if custom exception class wants a string explanation for its container
    {
        return $this->description." factory ".get_class($this)."(path={$this->path}, namespace={$this->namespace}, map: ".json_encode($this->manifest).")";
    }

}
```

and finally an example:

```
namespace jj;
require_once('lib/AbstractFactory.php');
require_once('lib/CurrenciesProvider.php'); //base abstract class for all banking objects that are created

class CurrencyProviders extends SimpleFactory
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $manifest = array(
          'Germany' => 'GermanBankCurrencies',
          'Switzerland' => 'SwissBankCurrencies'
        );

        parent::__construct($manifest, __DIR__.'/CurrencyProviders/', //you have total control over relative or absolute paths here
       'banks\');
        $this->description = 'currency provider country name';
    }


}
```

now do

```
$currencies_cache = (new \jj\CurrencyProviders())['Germany'];
```

or

```
$currencies_cache = (new \jj\CurrencyProviders())['Ukraine'];
```

> LogicException("Unknown currency provider country name Ukraine")

If there is no SwissCurrencies.php file in /CurrencyProviders/,

> \jj\SystemConfigurationException('Factory jj\CurrencyProviders was unable to produce a new class banks\SwissCurrencies. Debug data: currency provider country name factory jj\CurrencyProviders(path=/var/www/hosted/site/.../CurrencyProviders/, namespace=banks\, map: {"Germany": "GermanBankCurrencies", "Switzerland":"SwissBankCurrencies"}')

With enough effort this factory can be extended to catch parse errors ([How to catch error of require() or include() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261756/how-to-catch-error-of-require-or-include-in-php)) and pass arguments to constructors.