# How to catch error of require() or include() in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch, require, fatal-error

I'm writing a script in PHP5 that requires the code of certain files. When A file is not available for inclusion, first a warning and then a fatal error are thrown. I'd like to print an own error message, when it was not possible to include the code. Is it possible to execute one last command, if requeire did not work? the following did not work:

```
require('fileERROR.php5') or die("Unable to load configuration file.");
```

Supressing all error messages using `error_reporting(0)` only gives a white screen, not using error_reporting gives the PHP-Errors, which I don't want to show.

Answer (score 32):

You can accomplish this by using [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) in conjunction with [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php).

The example from the `ErrorException` page is:

```
<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

/* Trigger exception */
strpos();
?>
```

Once you have errors being handled as exceptions you can do something like:

```
<?php
try {
    include 'fileERROR.php5';
} catch (ErrorException $ex) {
    echo "Unable to load configuration file.";
    // you can exit or die here if you prefer - also you can log your error,
    // or any other steps you wish to take
}
?>
```

Comment: @SajnEvardsson php manual has ErrorException third parameter as $errno, not the second one.

Comment: The example above is copied directly from the ErrorException docs (link above) - in the "official" example they use $errno as $code, while others (including in the comments on that page) have suggested using it as $severity - note that if you like you can use it for both, or neither.

Comment: Seems like overly-engineered way of doing very simple thing

Comment: This is actually a useful solution in my situation. i have legacy (pre-framework!) code that has suffixes in filenames... `ClassA.class.php` or `InterfaceA.interface.php`. Long term goal: fix all that. Short term: reduce redundant file-exists checks by attempting both safely.

Answer (score 26):

I just use 'file_exists()':

```
if (file_exists("must_have.php")) {
    require "must_have.php";
}
else {
    echo "Please try back in five minutes...\n";
}
```

Comment: Better to use [is_readable()](http://www.php.net/is_readable); it checks for file existence, in addition of readability of the file (simply, a file must exist to be readable). Also, to prevent from including directories, you should use [is_dir()](http://www.php.net/is_dir) (i.e. !is_dir($filename)).

Comment: `file_exists` doesn't check include path so it may not work

Comment: incldue `die()` at the end of your echo. `require` will stop the script from running and if the file does not exist the echo will be shown and the rest of the page load. But instead addng `die()` at the will show nothing in the page other than the message.

Comment: It also works with DIRECTORIES, not only files, which is even better

Answer (score 4):

A  better approach would be to use [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) on the path first. `realpath` will return `false` if the file does not exist.

```
$filename = realpath(getcwd() . "/fileERROR.php5");
$filename && return require($filename);
trigger_error("Could not find file {$filename}", E_USER_ERROR);
```

You could even create your own require function in your app's [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) that wraps PHP's require function

```
namespace app;

function require_safe($filename) {
  $path = realpath(getcwd() . $filename);
  $path && return require($path);
  trigger_error("Could not find file {$path}", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere in your files

```
namespace app;

require_safe("fileERROR.php5");
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why, but your code does not work correctly (produces false positive), when run in PHP CLI / console. I.e. It halts execution of script, claiming, that file XYZ does not exists, while it actually does exists -- commenting out your code and going directly to `include()` works fine and file is included without errors.

Answer (score 3):

**As of PHP 7.0**, you can catch the [Throwable](https://www.php.net/throwable) exception thrown by `require()`.

```php
try {
    require '/path/not-found/or-not-available.php';
}
catch (Error $e) {
    // debugging example:
    die('Caught error => ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Will output something like:

> Caught error => Failed opening required '/path/not-found/or-not-available.php' [...]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use include(). Require(), when used on non-existent file, produces a fatal error and exits the script, so your die() won't happen. Include() only throws warning and then the script continues.

Comment: Your answer is either specific to a certain PHP version or specific to certain `php.ini` configuration. On my side (PHP 5.5.4) with my configuration, changing `require` to `include` brings absolutely no difference. Both are throwing ugly fatal errors, that I can't catch.

Comment: @trejder -  This is not correct Include throws a warning, but it carries on.  It is not fatal.  Whereas require throws an error and the program will stop.  It is true that both produce entries in `error.log`

Comment: @RohitGupta You are referring to my seven years old comment that talks about things 100% configuration specific. Are you sure that it is not possible to configure PHP the way that I describe? I don't know what was my PHP's configuration seven years ago, but I pretty much don't see a reason for which I would be writing here something that is not true. I rather think that I wrote what I was observing at that time and how my environment was actually behaving.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you took a look at the most [recent comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#106061) in the documentation for the [set_error_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function.

It suggests the following as a method (and with an example) of catching fatal errors:

```
<?php
function shutdown()
{
    $a=error_get_last();
    if($a==null)  
        echo "No errors";
    else
         print_r($a);

}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
ini_set('max_execution_time',1 );
sleep(3);
?>
```

I haven't tried the suggestion, but this could propably be used in other fatal error scenarios.

Comment: While this may work, it produces good question, if this will work in conditions, OP is asking? I believe that most people landing here are looking for a solution, where they can catch `require` on non-existing file **and continue** script execution. Being able to gracefully die (i.e. display something, I want but end up with script termination even so -- and that is what your code seems to be doing) doesn't seem to be fitting into many scenarios. I assume, script can display whatever it want's if it going to die. I want to prevent die / termination on non-existing file fed to `require`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way I am using is that

```
<?php
    ...
    if(!include 'config.php'){
        die("File not found handler. >_<");
    }
   ...
?>
```

Comment: any specific instance where this won't work?

Comment: I have downvoted you because this still generates a warning.  Execution still carries on, but it leaves two lines in your error log.  It is still an error condition, that you have not caught.