# why is try catch not working? What am I doing wrong? (php)

Tags: php

```
function TriggerContent($c, $db){
    try {
        include 'pages/' . $c . '.php';
        $content= getContent();
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $content = 'Error';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

What I want it do is display the `error` if the php file doesn't exists.
But it doesn't work...

What am I doing wrong?

Or will this just not work with try catch in php?

Comment: Use `file_exists()` and then `throw` an exception?

Comment: Does getContent() throw?

Comment: Are variables created inside try catch blocks acessible outside them? I really don't know.,

Comment: Hmmmm... How will I have to do that then? I got this assignment from my teacher and he said I had to use as less if/else as posible... So is there a way without them?

Comment: Have you reviewed solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261756/how-to-catch-error-of-require-or-include-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because a failed include doesn't throw an exception, it throws a warning. Therefor the `catch` block will never be executed, as you'll only enter it if there is an exception. You can just check if the file exists, and if it doesn't, throw an exception.

```
try {
    $page = 'pages/' . $c . '.php';

    if (!file_exists($page))
        throw new Exception('File does not exist: ['.$page.']');

    include $page;
    $content = getContent();

} catch (Exception $e){
    $content = 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

If the targeted file doesn't exist, it will output

> Error: File does not exist: [path-to-file]

in your `$content` variable.

Reference

- [PHP Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)
- [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) manual

Comment: I will accept this as the answer, but I actually thought try catch would work the same as in a language like C# where it always throw's an exception if something doesn't work...

Comment: PHP has multiple types of errors, not everything is an exception. You've got notices, warnings (these two *"can"* be ignored), exceptions (can be catched), and fatal errors (stops the execution). So if you want to handle something as an exception (in a try/catch) you'll have to specifically throw an exception. You also have `require` as opposed to `include`, but that throws a "fatal error", which isn't catchable (I might be wrong about that, but not by default anyway).

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning 'Error' and hoping instead to see the actual Exception message this line should replace your **$content = 'Error';**

```
$content = 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage();
```

Then your function will return $content including the message error string.