# PHP spl_autoload_register() flavors advantages/disadvantages

Tags: php, autoload, spl

The [`spl_autoload_register()` function](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) can be used with 3 types of callbacks: functions, static methods and regular methods. Are there any advantages/disadvantages for these 3 types compared to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really any major differences.

A closure (defined like the following (PHP 5.3+ only)) can never be unregistered, unless it is saved to a variable:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) { ... });
```

A static method can actually auto load the static class before running its autoloader

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if ($class === 'AutoLoader') {
        var_dump('Auto loading AutoLoader');
        class AutoLoader {
            public static function autoload($class) {
                var_dump(__CLASS__ . ' is loading: ' . $class);
            }
        }
    }
});

spl_autoload_register('AutoLoader::autoload');

Test::func();

// 'Auto loading AutoLoader'
// 'AutoLoader is loading: Test'
```

Although, I dont know why you would want to do that.

Static calls are easier to unregister though.

Either way you should follow the PSR0 auto loading standards: https://gist.github.com/221634

Answer (score 0):

If you use a non-static callable, there is an advantage of resolving file path and class namespace dynamically.

```
class SimpleFactory {
protected $path, $namespace;

    function __construct($path, $namespace) {
       $this->path = $path;
       $this->namespace = $namespace;
       spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoload'));
    }

    function __destruct() {
       spl_autoload_unregister(array($this, 'autoload'));
    }

    function produce($name) {
        if (class_exists($name, $autoload = true)) {
            return new $name();
        } else throw new RuntimeException("Unable to produce {$name}");
    }

    public function autoload($name) {
        $class_name = str_replace($this->namespace, '', $name);
        $filename = $this->path.$class_name.'.php';
        if (file_exists($filename))
            require $filename;
    }

}
```

try

```
 $a = new SimpleFactory('path1/', 'anames\\');
 $a1 = SimpleFactory->produce('a');
```

> get_class($a1) == anames\a

```
 $b = new SimpleFactory('path2/', 'bnames\\');
 $b1 = SimpleFactory->produce('a');
```

> get_class($b1) == bnames\a

For a more extensive example see my answer in [Throwing Exceptions in an SPL autoloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579080/throwing-exceptions-in-an-spl-autoloader/32893073#32893073)