# How to catch "class not found" error

Tags: php, autoload

I'm using [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to load certain classes when they are needed, but how can I catch the error when the class is not found by my autoload method?

Right now the only solution I see is to display a cute error message in my autoload callback and stop the application so that error never gets to show.

But I don't want to stop the application. I want to continue and skip the instantiation of the missing class I needed (in my specific case, they are not strictly required for the app to continue to run)

Comment: Similar post to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579080/throwing-exceptions-in-an-spl-autoloader).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/class_exists) before loading and handle the result appropriately. If it exists, instantiate as per usual. If it doesn't, skip the instantiation.

Comment: thanks! it works :D I feel pretty stupid for not thinking of trying that

Comment: Having to use `class_exists` before every instantiation is a pain, and using it triggers the loader anyway. Might as well just use it in the loader.

Comment: @Leigh Yes, it definitely should be implemented in the autoloader.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: Your "before loading" confused me, if you do `class_exists` in an autoloader, before loading (the file?), infinite loop ensues (or we hit a max recursion depth somewhere - not sure)?

Answer (score 2):

In order to mute the error you could dynamically create the missing classes when they are called, though I do not recommend such approach.

The following code worked for me:

```
function __autoload($name) {
eval("class {$name} {}");
}

echo 'pass 1';
$a = new a();
echo 'pass 2';
```

Comment: ewww... __autoload especially when OP is using spl_register_autoload