# Class 'Imagine\\Imagick\\Imagine' not found Symfony 2.1

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, liipimaginebundle

I want to integrate the [LiipImageBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/) in my Symfony 2.1 project.

I installed the bundle and the `imagine/Imagine v.0.4.0` bundle via composer.
It's seems to work fine, except, that the modified images are not saved.

The `error.log` states:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Imagine\\Imagick\\Imagine' not found in /var/www/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 365`

This line in `appProdProjectContainer.php` states:

```
protected function getLiipImagineService()
{
    return $this->services['liip_imagine'] = new \Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
}
```

I have no idea if this is correct or not. Have you guys any idea why PHP cannot find the class?

Comment: Did you install [imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php)? the only thing i can think of is that `Imagine\Imagick\Imagine` throws an Error if imagick is not installed, so the [autoloader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579080/throwing-exceptions-in-an-spl-autoloader) thinks it couldn't load `Imagine\Imagick\Imagine` instead.

Comment: Yes I did. `phpinfo()` states that it's active and using module version `3.1.0RC2`.

Comment: Btw: I just deinstalled imagick and if so, Symfony will throw an error in the very `Imagine` class. So the class is really not found, but it's there.

Comment: I switched to gd instead of imagemagick and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Imagine to autoload. If you haven't then u can do like this:

1. Open vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
2. Add

   ```
   'Imagine' => $vendorDir .'/imagine/Imagine/lib/',
   'Liip\\ImagineBundle' => $vendorDir . '/liip/imagine-bundle/',
   ```

Comment: You shouldn't change the content of `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` because the vendor folder usually isn't under SCM and this file can be auto re-generated.

Comment: Nowhere. Run `php composer.phar dumpautoload` (of couse you must use composer to install Imagine) and it should changes everything that is needed.

Comment: composer also re-generates this file, when using the command `update` or `install`.